# How to propagate Norfolk Island pine and asparagus fern ?

Tags: indoors, houseplants, propagation

How do I propagate two of my house plants or in other words how can I give this plant to someone else who wishes to grow it?

Photos of them are given below:

**Plant 1: Norfolk Island pine (*Araucaria heterophylla*)**

[image]

[image]

**Plant 2: asparagus fern (*Asparagus setaceus*)**

[image]

Comment: Can you split this to ask about propogating each of them seperately? The methods may not be the same across the plants.

Comment: funny you would pick these 2 plants, one very easy, one very difficult to propagate vegitatively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Araucaria heterophylla**

It is propogated by seeds.

**Asparagus setaceus**

It can be propogated by divisions i.e. cutting a stem and plant it at other place. You can place it in water bottle for few days till it's roots grow.

*Other method:* Asparagus setaceus gives birth to it's offsets (baby plants) near main stem which can be transplanted to new pot. Ensure that you **carefully** detach the offset from the mother plant to prevent it from any harm.

References: 
http://davesgarden.com/guides/pf/go/31757/#axzz2MlEiNWTY
http://davesgarden.com/guides/pf/go/2575/#ixzz2MlEwhdO5

Answer (score 2):

Yes, [Norfolk Island Pines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Araucaria_heterophylla) are propagated from seed. Practically speaking you need a mature specimen to get seeds.  This species is a hardwood tree that grows to 50 to 65 feet tall and is [hardy in USDA zone 10 to 11](http://www.floridata.com/ref/a/arau_het.cfm).

This [site](http://www.chileflora.com/Florachilena/FloraEnglish/E_Germination_Araucaria.htm) has a great description about growing a close Arucaria relative from seed which can be summed up as:

> The seeds of Araucaria araucana must be fresh to germinate, but when
> they are fresh, they germinate readily. In literature different
> methods for germinating the seeds are mentioned, but the safest way
> to achieve a 85 - 90 % germination is the following:
>
> Soak the seeds for about two days in water, then carry out a short
> cold stratification (put the seeds into a refrigerator for about 10 -
> 15 days in humid sand), and then plant them at 20º C or more. The
> seeds begin germination after 10 days, and by day 30 almost all of the
> seeds will have germinated. Because the seeds are quite big, the
> initial growth (10 -12 cm.) is very quick - it takes less than 90 days
> from the time you soak the seeds till you obtain the young plants of
> this size.

You can also propagate from tip cuttings but the literature indicates that only a cutting from the top of the tree will develop symmetrically.

> Take 6-8 in (15.2-20.3 cm) cuttings of the terminal leader in summer
> and treat with rooting hormone. Caution, cuttings from lateral
> branches will produce irregularly shaped trees.

Trees are grown commercially from seed but you need a mature tree.

Comment: I would like to add that rooting gymnosperms just doesn't usually work.